# ODE $y(1+2xy)dx+x(1-xy)dy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y(1+2xy)dx+x(1-xy)dy=0$$

I have tried to isolate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and got the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y(1+2xy)}{x(1-xy)}$$

but I understand that the terms have to be in the same order and that is not the case.

What should I do?

Comment: it is an equation of Abel type

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have just learned separation of variables and substation

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=xy$. Hence $\frac{du}{dx}=x\frac{dy}{dx}+y.$ Hence your equation became $$\frac{x}{u}\frac{du}{dx}-1 = \frac{1+2u}{u-1}.$$ This can be rewritten $$x\frac{du}{dx} = u\frac{3u}{u-1}$$ or else $$\frac{u-1}{3u^2}du=\frac{1}{x}dx.$$ Now you can integrate both sides.

Comment: You have dropped the minus sign which was in front of the fraction on your first line which means the following lines are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y(1+2xy)}{x(1-xy)}$$

Let $v=yx$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{-1}\frac{dv}{dx}-x^{-2}v$

$$x^{-1}\frac{dv}{dx}-x^{-2}v=-\frac{v(1+2v)}{x^2(1-v)}$$

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{3v^2}{(v-1)x}$$

$$\frac{v-1}{3v^2}\frac{dv}{dx}=x^{-1}$$

You can then integrate both sides.

$$\frac13\left(v^{-1}+\log|v|\right)=\log|x|+\frac{c}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{xy}+\log|y|+\log|x|=3\log|x|+c$$

$$\frac{1}{xy}+\log|y|-2\log|x|=c$$

To write this as a fuction of $y$ requires the [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Comment: I'm afraid @C. Dubussy has still got you after your last edit. His result integrates to $$\frac{y}{x^2}e^{\frac1{xy}}=C$$ which does satisfy the differential equation.

Comment: It would appear I am not immune to $+/-$ mistakes either. Thanks @user5713492

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}y(1+2xy)\ dx+x(1−xy)\ dy=0&\implies (y\ dx+x\ dy)+2xy^2\ dx-x^2y\ dy=0\\&\implies d(xy)=-xy(2y\ dx-x\ dy)\\&\implies \dfrac{d(xy)}{xy}=-2y\ dx+x\ dy\\&\implies\dfrac{d(xy)}{x^2y^2}=-2\dfrac{dx}{x}+\dfrac{dy}{y}\end{align*}I think you can take it from here.

Comment: isnt it $d(xy)=xy(-2ydx+xdy)$?

Comment: @gbox: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Given equation can be written as, 
ydx +xdy+2xy²dx- x²ydy=0

Dividing both side by (xy)², we get

d(xy)/(xy)² + 2dx/x - dy/y=0

Now it can be integrated easily...

Comment: Did you notice that your answer is exactly similar to what I have already posted?